# Cortar imagem css

Tags: html, css

Queria terminar de cortar a imagem em **css** completamente e tirar todas as bordas, porém eu só consigo cortar em baixo e do lado direito. Queria saber como eu poderia fazer para cortar completamente, está aqui o código que estou usando e a imagem.

**css:**

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 78px;
  width: 78px;
}

div img {
  clip:rect(110px,30px,300px,0px);
}
```

**html:**

```
<body> <div><img src="TESTE.jpg"></div> </body>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Faltou colocar o HTML também

Comment: <body>
        <div><img src="TESTE.jpg"></div> 
</body> e so um html normal com uma div e uma <img>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcelo isso acontece porque sua imagem não está centralizada dentro da div. Se vc centralizar sua imagem dentro da div vc consegue cortar ela por igual em todos os lados!

**OBS:** Não precisa de `clip:rect` até porque essa propriedade caiu em desuso https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip. Agora o indicado é usar `clip-path:polygon` segundo a **W3C** https://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1/#propdef-clip-path

Veja no exemplo e teste ai que vc vai ver que da certo! Aqui estou centralizando uma imagem de `200px` em uma `div.clip` de `100px` e "cortando" o que sobra de forma centralizada.

```css
.clip {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.clip img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clip"><img src="http://placecage.com/200/200" alt=""></div>
```